# Javascript: Adding a function to an object will also call it

Tags: javascript

I have an object that contains links that will be outputted.
For the "logout" link, I want to include a "logoutUser()" function.

However, when doing this, the "logoutUser()" function is called, hence logging out the user.

How can I add the function without calling it?

```
   {
        href: "#/",
        title: "Logga ut",
        role: "visitor",
        target: "_self",
        functionToBeCalledOnClick: logoutUser()
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: remove the () -> `functionToBeCalledOnClick: logoutUser`

Comment: Can you put more of your code? To better understand your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `()` this is what calls the function, and the output is stored in `functionToBeCalledOnClick`

```
{
    href: "#/",
    title: "Logga ut",
    role: "visitor",
    target: "_self",
    functionToBeCalledOnClick: logoutUser
}
```